# Dealing with time periods in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I'm developing a booking system in Rails 3.1. I have created a model for a Booking:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: bookings
#
# id           :integer         not null, primary key
# product_id   :integer
# customer_id  :integer
# booked_from  :datetime
# booked_to    :datetime
# paid         :boolean
# payment_type :string(255)
# created_at   :datetime
# updated_at   :datetime
#
```

So what I want to do is to validate each entry and check whether the desired time period (booked_from - booked_to) is overlapping any period of another booking with the same product_id. The products also have an available_from and available_to field which it also has to validate against.

How do I do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028612/reservation-type-system-w-validation-rails-3-0/5030662#5030662

Comment: Thanks, seems like that's a good way of doing it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this works:

```
class Booking
  validate :booking_period_not_overlapped
  private
    def booking_period_not_overlapped
      unless Booking.where(
        '(booked_from <= ? AND booked_to >= ?) OR (booked_from >= ? AND booked_from <= ?)',
        booked_from, booked_from,
        booked_from, booked_to
      ).empty?
        errors.add(:booked_from, 'Invalid period.')
      end
    end
end
```

It just checks if there is any existing records whose booked_from and booked_to satisfy one of the following conditions (suppose your new booking is from 16:00 to 17:00):

1. it starts before the new booking, and not yet ended (e.g. 15:00 - 16:30 or 15:00 - 17:30)
2. it starts within the new booking period (e.g. 16:20 - 16:50 or 16:30 - 17:30)

Comment: Works after adding errors.add(....) unless Booking.where... Add it to your answer so I can check it as being correct, also sqlite complains about the slash, so move up the line and remove it. Thanks!